How to implement Android custom dialer that should implement basic call,call transfer and conference that should replace android system default app?
I want implement android custom native dialer app that should be default app to handle incoming and outgoing calls.
I have done for basic call with hold/resume features by making my custom dialer as default phone.
Now I am adding features like call transfer and conference to my app. But unable to do so with my app.
I am new to android. Above basic app done  with help of some refernce.
Please help me implement call transfer and conference features in my custom native dialer app

Does this answer your question? Is there any API support to make conference calls programmatically in Android?

Implemented native dialer without Custom ConnectonService. For native dialer that should replace the default dialer of Androind is not solved by our custom ConnectionService due to a lack of system permissions.
The solution is our custom dialer app should use system's default ConnectionService Implementation TelephonyConnectionService.
Now I can do below,

Basic Calls (incoming and outgoing, Answer, Reject Call, Cancel Call, Disconnect),
Hold/resume
Conference  (Add Call and Merge)

We can implement whatever the default phone app supports.
